# Problems retrieving access token from Paypal android sdk

Tags: php, android, curl, paypal

I am trying to gain a token via the android paypal sdk. I created this cURL inside a php script, but I am unable to update my tkn column in my 000webhost database. The script is called from my app, but I think there might be something wrong with the script. Please let me know if you see anything wrong. Also, it might be that 000webhost does not allow cURL scripts. Please advise. On last minute, one thing that I noticed is that the variable "idclient" and "sekret" are not set as strings. Perhaps this is the problem. Please see if there are any other problems you might encounter.
Here's my script with the cURL:

```
<?php

require "quimasetup.php";
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$phone_number= $_POST["phone_number"];
$subject= $_POST["subject"];
$grade= $_POST["grade"];
$payment_id = $_POST["payment_id"];
$idclient = AVe40dqVhDDmGDbLhNEkH6G9eWyvgrqPrkKAucGv;
$sekret = ELQ595K9VZyfQcJuj7pw1yPVVv7OnNw;

$ch = curl_init("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $idclient.":".$sekret);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);


$json = json_encode($result);
$jsonn = json_decode($json);
$tkn = $jsonn->access_token;


$sql = "insert into craddle           values('$name','$email','$phone_number','$subject','$grade','$payment_id','$tkn');";

if (isset($tkn)){
if(mysqli_query($connection,$sql)){

echo "<br><h3>one row inserted...</h3>";

}
else{
echo "Error in insertion...".mysqli_error($connection);

}
}
else{
var_dump($json);
var_dump($jsonn);
var_dump($tkn); 
}

?>
```

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", TRUE);

Comment: I guess adding this piece of code will print out all errors. @Kkinsey

Comment: It should; and, possibly, give you a hint as to what is wrong.  You said, "it may be that my host doesn't allow cURL" ... well, that's the first thing to investigate.  So, do they?  A cURL error there might tell you. :-)

Comment: I included the piece of code you gave me to show errors, but i formatted it like this:  error_reporting(-1)  i read that an argument of -1 will give all possible errors. After i executed the script, i received no errors on my browser server response. I guess is safe to try from my app now. @Kkinsey

Comment: -1 isn't guaranteed to equate to E_ALL on all systems.  I'd suggest trying E_ALL:  error_reporting(E_ALL) -- but only in your development environment.